# yum is not working

Tags: yum

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install percona
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Bad id for repo: not installed, byte =   3
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. 6Server.10 is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6Server.10/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6Server.10/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml 
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Comment: Is your OS CentOS or Redhat?

Comment: RHEL6[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-71.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:26:34 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Comment see: [How do I re-register my system with Red Hat Network (RHN) Classic or Red Hat Satellite?](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/8036).  I'll update this answer as you work through the issues.

Comment: i dont want to use rhn_register because it is asking about login name and password.

Comment: `Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Bad id for repo: not installed, byte =   3
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.`
Your repos are missing because your system isn't registered.  Theres no way to reset the repos unless you reregister your system AFAIK, And according to your running kernel, the last successful build was 2010...

Answer (score 0):

- Disable the Redhat official REPO if you're not willing to register your machine
- I might be wrong, but Percona (server) is not included in the official RH repos
- In your case, YUM is looking for "Percona" into mirror.centos.org ... and is not finding it -> this is expected :)

Solution: Download the RPM from Percona's website http://www.percona.com/downloads/ (ex. http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.6/LATEST/binary/redhat/6/x86_64/) and install it.
I remember that some time ago they had a repo with their software ... not the case anymore.